# Sort PHP's +/- date string units

Tags: php, string, sorting, date, time

Given an array of miscellaneous strings used in PHP's time and date functions

```
[ '+7 day', '+2 week', '+5 month', '+1 week', '+10 day', '+2 year', '+1 day', ... ]
```

How would you sort these into:

```
[ '+1 day', '+7 day', '+1 week', '+10 day', '+2 week', '+5 month', '+2 year', ... ]
```

Comment: Write your own comparte function (for http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and make it use the parsed values...

Answer (score 1):

Not really efficient and quite ugly:

```
<?php
define('DATEINTERVAL_FORMAT', '%R%Y%M%D%H%I%S');
$intervals = [ '+7 day', '+2 week', '+5 month', '+1 week', '+10 day', '+2 year', '+1 day', /*...*/ ];

usort(
    $intervals,
    function ($a, $b) {
        $da = DateInterval::createFromDateString($a);
        $db = DateInterval::createFromDateString($b);

        return strcmp($da->format(DATEINTERVAL_FORMAT), $db->format(DATEINTERVAL_FORMAT));
    }
);

var_dump($intervals);
```

Result:

```
array(7) {
[0]=>
string(6) "+1 day"
[1]=>
string(6) "+7 day"
[2]=>
string(7) "+1 week"
[3]=>
string(7) "+10 day"
[4]=>
string(7) "+2 week"
[5]=>
string(8) "+5 month"
[6]=>
string(7) "+2 year"
}
```